# Scapy - get my own MAC address

Tags: scapy

How do I get the MAC address of the interface I am sending packets with?

I am trying to create a custom ARP packet, and I need to include my own MAC in it. I can not seem to find a way to get it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the get_if_hwaddr() function.

**Doc:** https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/routing.html

This code may help you :

```
my_macs = [get_if_hwaddr(i) for i in get_if_list()]
```

Cheers,
K.

Comment: Would have been better if you explained what `get_if_hwaddr` and `get_if_list` do.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily by:

```
from scapy.all import Ether
print(Ether().src)
```

This prints the MAC address of the default interface you're using.

Comment: `get_if_hwaddr(conf.iface)` is the same, but less mysterious.

Answer (score -1):

The Netifaces Python Package provides a great amount of information about the interfaces you are working with.

```
>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('en0')
{18: [{'addr': '00:12:34:56:78:9a'}], 2: [{'broadcast':
'10.255.255.255', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'addr': '10.16.1.4'}],
 30: [{'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', 'addr':
'fe80::123:4567:89ab:cdef%en0'}]}
```

http://alastairs-place.net/projects/netifaces/